# Shall we use log(diff(x)) or diff(log(x))?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, trend, logarithm

I am starting to learn time series and when detrending I always end up with the same doubt...

Generally, I use `diff()` for, let's say there is an upward trend like inflation... and I use `log()` to stabilise the variance.

My question is: given time series `x`, is there a rule when we shall do

```
log(diff(x))
```

Instead of

```
diff(log(x))
```

(code is in R language).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want log first, as the diff could be negative

Comment: Note: `diff` is fine for getting rid of stochastic trends, but not of deterministic ones. In the latter case, it introduces a unit-root moving average component (something you do not want).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lets's have at look at both options.

### `diff(log(x))`

`diff(log(x))` calculates relative changes. This also takes care of exponential trends. For example, you would use this to detrend the stock price development of Google. According to the logarithms laws:
$$log(a) - log(b) = log(a/b)$$

```
all.equal(log(3) - log(5), log(3/5))
```

This means, instead of using the absolute difference for detrending you are using the relative change. As a bonus differences calculated using the natural logarithm can also be interpreted as a precentage change. For more information I recommend:

Cole, T. J., & Altman, D. G. (2017). Statistics Notes: Percentage differences, symmetry, and natural logarithms. BMJ, 358(August), j3683. https://doi.org/10.1136/bmj.j3683

### `log(diff(x))`

On the other hand `log(diff(x))` calculates the absolute differences before the logarithm is applied. If you calculate a trend using this method, the trend would be more outlier resistant (but this also applies to `diff(log(x))`). This is helpful if there are a small number of big jumps in the time-series. Beware this method would potentially break your analyses when the difference is 0 or negative. (in R: `log(0) = -Inf` or `log(-1) = NaN`)

---

In my opinion `diff(log(x))` is the better default choice. While there probably is a use-case for `log(diff(x))`, it's quite hard to think of one.